# is unity DOTS mature enough to build a whole project on it?

Tags: unity, multithreading, entity-component-system

maybe you assume this question opinion based but its not. please read the whole question.

the question has 2 aspects.

1. are all features implemented? just better say, can i do everything or any gameplay i did on monobehaviours, on the DOTS? all are needed features implemented? including Ai, navigation, physics, animations and...
2. the bigger problem about DOTS and ECS is software engineering. DOTS gives us much better performance in memory and performance and parallel processing but it takes all good OOP practices from us.

as you may know, DOTS is not OO and uses its own architectures. most of references values are gone in dots to make data more compact. so there is no solid principles. dependency injections and all those OO design patterns. instead we have a hardly coupled code and entities.

the question is: does DOTS and ECS really lacks software engineering or its just we dont know enough about it and there are standards about it?

many people say that you should make all project on old monobehaviours and you can migrate section that are expensive to DOTS.

im not really sure what is the right approach for using with new technology.

Comment: Looks like many DOTS-related features are still in Preview or even Experimental: https://unity.com/dots/packages#unity-physics-preview

You should probably start making your game with regular MonoBehaviours and only use DOTS if you find that there are performance bottlenecks.

Comment: @Kevin that looks to me like as objective an answer as we're likely to get to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [many DOTS-related features are still in Preview or even Experimental](http://unity.com/dots/packages#unity-physics-preview). As of December 2020:

- **Entities**: Preview
- **Physics**: Preview
- **Netcode**: Preview
- **DSPGraph** (audio): Experimental
- **Animation**: Experimental
- **DOTS Runtime**: Preview

You should probably start making your game with regular MonoBehaviours and only use DOTS if you find that there are performance bottlenecks.

I have not worked with DOTS, but it sounds like the development tools/libraries/coding style are so drastically different that it's almost better to think of it as a separate engine. My impression is that DOTS will be best suited for large teams/AAA projects.

Answer (score 1):

I’m currently building a dots project and I’m using the new netcode too. It’s definitely ready, but by no means easy. And once in a while you’ll have to deal with breaking changes or bugs. But I would stay it’s stable enough to build a prototype from. Maybe not if you plan on releasing in the very near future. But maybe if you’re looking at mid-late next year.

As for it not being OO, on the contrary. Once my brain figured out the new patterns I’m actually finding it extremely clean and object oriented.  Think of the objects more as message objects, tag objects, and data objects. The systems are objects that do a single behaviour of your program. There’s definitely way more abstraction. So you won’t have the same mapping of real world object to code object that you sometimes find in traditional unity code. But maybe that’s a good thing.

Edit: this is more of the composition vs inheritance approach. It follows a similar idea. But still OO.

There’s definitely a learning curve.